# Trouble passing multiple labels between view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols, viewcontroller

I am stuck on a delegates, protocols issue in an attempt to pass data between two view controllers.

I am able to pass data, but when I try to alter the user inputs, by adding two user inputs together and then pass that data through I get stuck.  Could someone explain where I made my mistake?  Thank you kindly.

I'm sorry if this is a novice question.  But I've been struggling with it for a while now.  Thank you again.

my View Controller.m file
    #import "ViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)setTheValues
{
int numberOne = [_numberOne.text intValue];
int numberTwo = [_numberTwo.text intValue];
int sumTotal = (numberOne+numberTwo);
sumTotal = [_sumTotal.text intValue];
//  self.sumTotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sumTotal];
}

 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"vc2"])
{
SecondViewController *vc2 = [segue destinationViewController];
NSString *passedMessage = _textField.text;
vc2.passedMessage = passedMessage;
    [self setTheValues];
    NSString *passedMessageTwo = _sumTotal.text;
    vc2.passedMessageTwo = passedMessageTwo;

}
}

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 - (IBAction)sendOver:(UIButton *)sender {
  [self setTheValues];
}
 @end
```

View Controller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <sendMessage>

- (IBAction)sendOver:(UIButton *)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberOne;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberTwo;

// declaring sumTotal
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sumTotal;
@end
```

My Second View Controller.h
    #import

```
@protocol sendMessage <NSObject>

@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)goBack:(UIButton *)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelTwo;

//delegate property

@property(retain)id <sendMessage> delegate;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *passedMessage;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *passedMessageTwo;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *passedMessageThree;

 @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED, based on issued pointed out by danh:

It looks to me like your setTheValues method is wrong. This is your (incorrect) code:

```
-(void)setTheValues
{
  int numberOne = [_numberOne.text intValue];
  int numberTwo = [_numberTwo.text intValue];

  //This line adds the wales of the 2 strings. That's good.
  int sumTotal = (numberOne+numberTwo);

  //This line throws away the value from the last line 
  //and replaces it with the contents of _sumTotal. That's not right.
  sumTotal = [_sumTotal.text intValue];
}
```

---

Better to do it like this:

```
-(int) calcTotal;
{
  int numberOne = [_numberOne.text intValue];
  int numberTwo = [_numberTwo.text intValue];

  //This line adds the wales of the 2 strings. That's good.
  int sumTotal = (numberOne+numberTwo);
  return sumTotal;
}
```

Then rewrite your prepareForSegue method:

```
 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"vc2"])
  {
    SecondViewController *vc2 = [segue destinationViewController];

    vc2.delegate = self;

    NSString *passedMessage = _textField.text;
    vc2.passedMessage = passedMessage;

    //Call calcTotal to read the inputs and return their sum as an integer.
    int total = [self calcTotal];

    //convert the sum to a string.
    NSString *passedMessageTwo = [NSString stringWithFormat: "%d", total];
    vc2.passedMessageTwo = passedMessageTwo;
  }
}
```

BTW, your code has a mixture of "retain" and "strong"/"weak" qualifiers on your properties. You can't do that. "retain" is used in manual reference counted code. "strong" and "weak" are used in ARC. If you're not using ARC, you should be. Switch to ARC, then switch that "retain" to nonatomic, strong.

You also have a "delegate" property (That's the one that's declared as retain) that you never set or use at all. You should set that in your prepareForSegue method

Comment: I don't think so.  sumTotal is a UILabel.  OP's commented line self.sumTotal.text = ... looks more correct.

Comment: Duncan - thank you, that resolved the issue and has allowed me to do what I needed to.  Thank you.

Comment: @flooie, you may mark the answer correct if you think it's correct.  (I don't see how it can be, the code assigns and int as the sum and then abandon's it on the stack.  It also wrongly declares the delegate as "retain" and never sets or refers to it).  These things are not addressed in the answer.

Comment: @danh, what are you talking about? There is no mention of a delegate anywhere in this thread. Also, the OP is using ARC, so there is also no mention of retain. Further, the method calcTotal that I wrote returns it's result as the method result, and does not "abandon it on the stack."

Comment: Please search for "delegate" on this page.  I don't know if it's an ARC project, but please search for "retain" on this page.  You'll find both in the OP.  Please review the code you posted in the method called setTheValues.  It computes an int and abandons it on the stack.  (Also, please don't take it as an insult.  I can see that you're answer is helpful here, just trying to consider the next reader who might learn something wrong from it).

Comment: @danh, look at my code more closely. In my version of the method, which I call calcTotal, I calculate the sum in a local variable called sumTotal, but then I return it as the function result. The method "setTheValues" was a commented quote of the OPs (flawed) method. As to whether the OP is using ARC or not, you're right, there is a property that's declared as retain. I missed that. There are also properties declared as weak and strong. The code can't compile with both, so something is wrong. (The compiler won't accept the "retain" qualifier when building for ARC.)

Comment: I agree with what you are saying here.  What I'm saying is all that belongs in your answer minus the OP's incorrect code.  Just to help the next person who lands here. (Sorry I missed the helpful comment you added to the OP setTheValues method).